iOS 18 breaks design of SwiftUI Toggle buttons (Edit: fixed by Apple)
Update: Appears to be fixed with iOS 18 beta 5 (or earlier).
inside a List, I have a simple Toggle.
I use this in the main column of a NavigationSplitView.
The following is the complete runnable simplified code that demonstrates the problem:
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private  var on = true
    @State private var visibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $visibility) {
            List {
                Text(getCurrentiOSVersion())
                Toggle(isOn: $on) {
                    Text("Some long talkative text explaing way more than I should in a toggle")
                }
            }
        } detail: {
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)

    }
    
    func getCurrentiOSVersion() -> String {
        let systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
        return "iOS Version: \(systemVersion)"
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

running on iOS 16 or 17, it looks like this:

running on iOS 18, it looks like this:

On iOS 18, with different text lengths, the toggle Button is sometimes rendered on the left and sometimes on the right, which I find ugly.
Any idea what I can do that the Button is always trailing like with iOS 16 and iOS 17?

You should submit a feedback to Apple. https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

Sent feedback to Apple.

Seems like a new default behavior!
Try mimicking the previous one yourself like:
HStack { //  Make sure this will be stacked horizontally
    Text("Some long talkative text explaing way more than I should in a toggle") //  Add the leading text in place
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) //  Make it always fill the space
    Toggle(isOn: $on) {
        Text("Some long talkative text explaing way more than I should in a toggle")
    }
    .labelsHidden() //  Hides the default label keeping the accessibility stuff
}


P.S.: You have a typo in explaing

Nice. I missed that .labelsHidden(). To handle also short texts, an additional Spacer() is needed.
